# White bar across the top of Meta's header

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

Meta's header has a weird white bar across the top:

[image: white bar across top of meta header]

It scrolls with the rest of the header, so I only see this when at the top of the page. On a spot-check, Puzzling and Literature seem unaffected.

I'm on the latest version of Chrome and Windows with a Samsung laptop. My moto g(6) (also Chrome) can reproduce.

Comment: I too have this issue. Firefox 93.0, Windows 10.

Comment: I noticed this just started happening a few minutes ago and was about to report it. Note I checked my over 20 other sites I'm a member of, with none of them having this problem.

Comment: Repro on Brave (most recent). Unnecessary take-up of space.

Comment: Saw this a few minutes ago after dismissing a banner on Stack Overflow. Thought it might be related, but apparently not.

Comment: interestingly my white bar was in a different location, i assume because my top bar isn't sticky

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thank you for reporting! If you look carefully, the space is being caused by a rogue semicolon way over on the left. My bad! I'm canary-testing some infrastructure work on Meta. Fix is on the way.

Comment: That was a quick answer!

Comment: @RandomPerson They call me the fastest gun in the repo! Fix should be live now.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Yup. Looks like the white bar is gone now.